# copy constructor for struct containing a union

Tags: c++, unions

Consider the code

```
struct S
{
    S(){...}
    union
    {
        int* pi;
        double* pd;
    }
    // additional member functions etc
};
```

Suppose we also have setters for `pi` and `pd`, that is, memory is being allocated depending on which member of the union is being selected.

How would you write a copy constructor for `S`? How can you know which member of the union is "active"? One way is to have an additional flag that you set when you "activate" one of the members, is there any other way?

Comment: You'll want to create a tagged union. Add an extra enum (or bool or int) that remembers what member was allocated.

Comment: + 1, though it seems like this is a general problem, not specific to copy-constructors: you *always* need to know which element of the union is the one that you can safely use!

Comment: And since this is vaguely tricky to get right, just use `boost::variant` instead of an enum, always.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How can you know which member of the union is "active"?

You can't, unless you store a flag to tell you which way it has been assigned. It is common to store such "selector" flag in the enclosing class, for example:

```
struct S
{
    S(){...}
    union
    {
        int* pi;
        double* pd;
    }
    enum {
        UseIntPtr,
        UseDoublePtr
    } unionSelector;
    // additional member functions etc
};
```

You would set `unionSelector` to `UseIntPtr` when you set `pi`, or to `UseDoublePtr` when you set `pd`. Then you would have a flag to use in your copy constructor, assignment operator, and so on.

Comment: thanks, that's what I though, wanted to double check as it seems a bit "non-elegant" and wanted to make sure I'm not missing something.

Comment: Unions are inelegant. They are rarely used in C++, and are mostly a holdover from C.

Comment: @Brian: They are possibly more elegant than using placement new to reconstruct an object in-place with a new data type.

Comment: @ZanLynx If the new data type in question has a nontrivial constructor, then you will have to use placement new even if you are using a union. Otherwise, undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

If the union is a POD (Plain Old Data) then you can use `memcpy`. Works great.

In your case you'd have to give the union a name so you can do `sizeof myunion`.

`memcpy(&this->myunion, &other.myunion, sizeof myunion)`

Comment: how would this copy the allocated memory of the individual pointers? Or by POD you mean plain data types excluding pointers?

Comment: @vsoftco: It copies the pointer, both pointer copies hold the same address, ala shared_ptr.

Comment: @BenVoigt yes, but that's not usually what one wants (except perhaps in COW situations, but even in that case you need a deep copy when modifying). In general you want to deep copy the memory.

Comment: If you only wanted to copy the pointers (you probably don't, do a deep copy instead) you could just add an extra uintptr_t field to that union. memcpy for a single pointer is a bit overkill.

Comment: @tux3: `uintptr_t` has to be able to represent any pointer value and roundtrip.  The in-memory representation doesn't have to be compatible though.  Most compilers treat `memcpy` as an intrinsic anyway.